# Azure Webjob: Why does all my code get shown in the log and not executed?

Tags: php, azure, facebook-graph-api, azure-webjobs

I have uploaded a zip file (with a PHP file, and a dependancy folder) as a WebJob into Azure.

When a webjob executes correctly, none of the code inside the PHP file shows on the log. In fact, all that shows is this:

```
[10/21/2016 00:00:00 > 28555d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[10/21/2016 00:00:01 > 28555d: SYS INFO] Run script 'cronjob.php' with script host - 'PhpScriptHost'
[10/21/2016 00:00:01 > 28555d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[10/21/2016 00:00:42 > 28555d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

I've uploaded another WebJob that has vaguely similar PHP code but involves calls to the `Facebook Graph API`. The problem I'm seeing is that none of my code gets executed, and instead is it being echo'ed out into the log, like so:

```
[10/21/2016 00:00:00 > 28555d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[10/21/2016 00:00:01 > 28555d: SYS INFO] Run script 'cronjob.php' with script host - 'PhpScriptHost'
[10/21/2016 00:00:01 > 28555d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[10/21/2016 19:43:15 > 28555d: INFO] <?
[10/21/2016 19:43:15 > 28555d: INFO] require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
[10/21/2016 19:43:15 > 28555d: INFO]  try {
[10/21/2016 19:43:15 > 28555d: INFO] ....
[10/21/2016 19:43:15 > 28555d: INFO] ....
[10/21/2016 19:43:15 > 28555d: INFO] ....
[10/21/2016 19:43:15 > 28555d: INFO] ....
[10/21/2016 19:43:16 > 28555d: INFO] ?>
[10/21/2016 19:43:16 > 28555d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

Not even any `echo` calls are shown in the log aside from how they are seen in the actual code, as code.

Has anyone seen this before? What could be happening here?

Comment: is php on that system configured for short_open_tags? `<?` != `<?php`, if so. Remember, there's no such thing as a "php script". There's only files which have PHP code blocks inside them. if you don't have the proper `<?php`-opener, PHP will never engage and the file's contents are simply treated as output.

Comment: @MarcB Thx, I have been searching for hours to get my PHP script working. Vote for you :)

Comment: Hi, @VolcovMeter, dose Marc's comment solve your issue?

Comment: @MarcB is correct!

Comment: @MarcB Would you like to post your comment as an answer? That was the solution.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT yes